# group_by filter to groups that share at least one matching value

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

Filter out grouped observations in a dataframe that do not share at least one value of a specified column.

I would like to keep only groups where at least two of the observations share the same age.

```
df<-data.frame(list(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                household = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                age= c(19, 19, 45, 2,15,50))`
```

so the final data.frame should only include household == 1,
and should look like:

id household age
 1   1  19
 2   1  19
 3   1  45

Comment: Yes, I was using dplyr. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look at the length of `age` for each group and compare it to the length of `unique(age)`. If `length(age) > length(unique(age))` at least two of the observations share an age.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  filter(length(age) > length(unique(age)))

#      id household   age
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1         1    19
# 2     2         1    19
# 3     3         1    45
```

@Dave2e pointed out another more `dplyr`-y way to do this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  filter(n() > n_distinct(age))
```

Comment: If you want to stay in the dplyr world then: `filter(n() > n_distinct(age))` is an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
df <- data.frame(list(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    household = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                    age= c(19, 19, 45, 2,15,50)))
```

```
df %>%
  filter(household == 1)
```

Comment: OP's goal is *"I would like to keep only groups where at least two of the observations share the same age."* It just happens that `household = 1` is the solution for their sample data.